# Is $L^p \cap L^q$ dense in $L^r$?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

It is known that $L^p \cap L^q \subset L^r$, where $1 \le p \le r \le q \le \infty$. Are all of these inclusions dense? I.e., do we have 
\begin{equation*}
\overline{L^p \cap L^q} = L^r
\end{equation*}
(closure w.r.t. $\Vert \cdot \Vert_r$)?

To prove this, one would have to show the existence of a sequence of functions $f_n \in L^p \cap L^q$ such that $f_n \stackrel{L^r}{\longrightarrow} f$, given arbitrary $f \in L^r$. I know how this works in the case $p=1$, $q=\infty$. But is it even true in the most general case?

If it is true, as a consequence, **any** function in $L^p$ could be approximated by functions $f_n \in L^q$ for **any** $1 \le q \le \infty$. This sounds quite like a utopia to me, as it would make a lot of things I am currently working on easier. I don't see why it would be wrong, however. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $f\in L^r$, and define $f_n:=f\chi_{\{n^{-1}\leqslant |f|\leqslant n\}}.$ We have $f_n\in L^p\cap L^q$ for each $n$, and by monotone convergence, $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_r\to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the proof does not work for $r = \infty$ since we cannot apply the monotone convergence theorem in that case. See Calvin Khor answer below for a counterexample.

Answer (score 6):

The result is false for $p<r=q=\infty$, which would read
$$ \overline{L^p\cap L^\infty} \overset{?}{=} L^\infty$$
For instance take $1\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with Lebesgue measure; if $\|f-1\|_{L^\infty}\le 1/2$ then say $|f|\ge 1/4$ a.e. so $f\notin L^p$ as $\int_{\mathbb R} |f|^p = \int_{|f|\ge 1/4} |f|^p \ge \frac1{4^p}\int_\mathbb R 1 = \infty. $ So no collection of $f\in L^p$, in particular $f\in L^p\cap L^\infty$ can approximate $1$.

Comment: I don't need a vote, can someone just tell me I'm not going crazy? Did >6 years go by without one person out of 1k views noticing a case was wrong?

Comment: You are not crazy. The monotone convergence theorem cannot be invoked when $r = \infty$ so the accepted answer does not work in that case and your counterexample seems correct to me.