# Density Lp spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

If $ 1 \leq p \leq r \leq q < \infty$ and $f \in L^r(\mathbb{R})$. Why is $f \chi _{\lbrace x : \frac{1}{n} \leq |f| \leq n \rbrace} \in L^p \cap L^q $ for all n?
I've tried to show that the set ${\lbrace x : \frac{1}{n} \leq |f| \leq n \rbrace}$ is of finite measure by using chebychev-ish bounds but this hasn't gotten me anywhere.
(This question refers to [Is $L^p \cap L^q$ dense in $L^r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652033/is-lp-cap-lq-dense-in-lr)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inequalities $|f|^p \le  n^{r-p} |f|^r$ and $|f|^q \le n^{q-r} |f|^r$ which are both valid on the set $\{1/n \le |f| \le n\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Should the first inequality be $|f|^p \leq n^{p-r}|f|^r$ ?

Comment: If $n^{-1} \le |f|$ then $n^{p-r} \le |f|^{r-p}$ which rearranges to $|f|^p \le n^{r-p} |f|^r$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact any bounded measurable function on a set $E$ of finite measure belongs to $L^s(E), 0 < s\le \infty.$ That has a very simple proof. Now in your problem, set $E= \{1/n\le |f| \le n\}.$ To show $E$ has finite measure, note

$$\infty > \int_E |f|^r \ge (1/n)^r\mu(E).$$

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!  What is the proof of the theorem you stated (or do you know where I can find it)?

Comment: Suppose $b$ is the bounded measurable function. Then obviously $b\in L^\infty(E),$ and for $0<s<\infty$ $\int_E |b|^s\, d\mu \le (\|b\|_\infty)^s\cdot \mu (E).$