# $\overline{L^{n+1}}=L^p$ for $1\leq n\leq p \leq n+1<\infty$ for $\mu(X)<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

After reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652033/is-lp-cap-lq-dense-in-lr) post, I began thinking that this is true. My thought process the following. Let $n\leq p \leq n+1$ for $n\geq 1$.
$$\overline{L^{n+1}}=\overline{L^{n+1}\cap L^{n+1}}\subseteq \overline{L^n\cap L^{n+1}}=L^p.$$

Does this chain work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Note that continuous functions are dense in any of these $L^q$ spaces.