# Density in $L^p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to use similar arguments used here  [Is $L^p \cap L^q$ dense in $L^r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652033/is-lp-cap-lq-dense-in-lr) , to prove that for every $r\in [p,\infty )$ the space $L^r$ is dense in $L^p$.

I am trying to find a sequence in $L^r$ that will converge in an arbitrary element of $L^p$. I saw some similar arguments and get the idea, but I am rusty on my measure theory.

Comment: Hint: simple functions.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I already have in front of a solution,but it's something I wouldn't think of, so I am trying to find something else (online or here). Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: Simple functions are contained in both spaces and are dense in both spaces.

Comment: What is your measure space? In general $L^{r}$ need not even be a subset of $L^{p}$ for $r \geq p$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Without any information on the measure spacee the statement is wrong. Your argument only shows that $L^{p} \cap L^{r}$ is dense in $L^{p}$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy right. Obviously OP needed conditions on the measure space in order for the premise to even hold, so..

Comment: The space is a bounded subset of $R^n$ @KaboMurphy (does this help?) oh boy I am so ignorant here, reading your comments.

Comment: Also @Cameron Williams what is OP?

Comment: @Iniciador stands for "original poster"

Comment: @Iniciador If the space is bounded in $\mathbb R^{n}$ then $L^{r} \subset L^{p}$ for al $r \geq p$ and the statement is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your measure space is such that $L^{r} \subset L^{p}$ then you can prove that $L^{r}$ is dense in $L^{p}$ as follows:
Let $f \in L^{p}$. For any positive integer $n$ define $f_n=fI_{|f| \leq n}$. Then $f_n \in L^{r}$ because $\int |f_n|^{r} =\int |f|^{p}|f|^{r-p} I_{|f| \leq n}\leq n^{r-p}\int |f|^{p} <\infty$. Now $f_n \to f$ in $L^{p}$ by DCT.

[ $\int |f-f_n|^{p}=\int |f|^{p}I_{|f| >n}$, $|f|^{p}I_{|f| >n} \to 0$ almost everywhere and $|f|^{p}I_{|f| >n}$ is dominated by $|f|^{p}$ which is integrable].