# Prove that $L^p\cap L^q$ is dense in $L^r$.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I have the next question: given $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ a p.m.s. and $1\leq p<r<q$ then 
$$
\overline{L^p(\mu)\cap L^q(\mu)} = L^r(\mu)
$$
with respect to $||\cdot||_r$.

I already know that $L^p(\mu)\cap L^q(\mu)\subset L^r(\mu)$. And in other post where this question was asked they said to consider $f\in L^r$ and $f_n = f\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{n^{-1}\leq |f| \leq n\}}$ and that $f_n\in L^p(\mu)\cap L^q(\mu)$, but i dont understand why this is true, why does $f_n\in L^p(\mu)\cap L^q(\mu)$.

I hope someboy can help me with this.

Comment: $\mu$ is a finite measure and $f_n$ is bounded function so it has integrals of all powers.

Comment: @rubikscube09 if the measure is not finite, then this is false?

Comment: My guess is that $f \in L^r(\mu)$?  If so, then you know $\{|f| \geq n^{-1}\}$ has finite measure.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh, i forgot to include that, u are right. Now let me try to understand the last part

Comment: typo on line 1: $q < r < q$.

Comment: @copper.hat obvious typo

Comment: Why not consider the simple function which are???

Comment: @UmbertoP. Fixed, thanks

Comment: what simple function?

Comment: The simple functions, I mean.

Comment: Aah, use the fact that $S_\mu = \{s\in S(\Omega,\mathbb{R})\;:\;\mu(\{s\not = 0\})<\infty\}$ is dense in $L^r$? In a book i read that this can be used, but i'm not sure how. Even so i'd like to understand fully why $f_n$ is in that intersection, so i know how somebody came up with it

Comment: @Zekess: Yes, that is correct and the simple functions (whose support has finite measure) are in all the $L^k$ spaces and also dense.

Comment: @copper.hat Ooh, so $f_n$ are simple functions (whose support has finite measure), so they must be on $L^p$ and $L^q$??

Comment: Yep. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks a lot, finally i can understand it!. Seems like i needed fresh air xD. Its my first post, idk how should i proceed now that i got the answer in the comments tho D:

Comment: I looked earlier but didn't find any dup, but I looked again and I think this might be a nicer answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652039/27978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $f_n$ belongs to $L^p\cap L^q$ follows from the inequalities 
$$
\lvert f_n\rvert^p=\lvert f_n\rvert^r\lvert f_n\rvert^{p-r}\leqslant \lvert f\rvert^r\lvert f_n\rvert^{p-r}\leqslant  \lvert f\rvert^rn^{r-p}
$$
and 
$$
\lvert f_n\rvert^q=\lvert f_n\rvert^r\lvert f_n\rvert^{q-r}\leqslant \lvert f \rvert^r\lvert f_n\rvert^{q-r}\leqslant \lvert f \rvert^r n^{q-r}.
$$

Comment: Ooh, now is quite clear. Thanks a lot!